# Fill google form with script

Tags: python

I need to fill form like this [my_google_form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13pJBKD9hS3w65ICXyNqNi4uSCn1hdt3qz-BuGjVGN-Q/viewform) with some script.
I try Python Mechanize

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13pJBKD9hS3w65ICXyNqNi4uSCn1hdt3qz-BuGjVGN-Q/viewform")

for form in br.forms():
    print "Form name:", form.name
    print form
```

but it doesn't  see form in this link.

Comment: Consider selenium  ?

Comment: consider any suggestions

Comment: Why to fill a test form?